# Best Rowkey Design for Hbase Table

Tags: hbase, row-key

We have a Hbase Table where they rowkey is prepared by concatenating Site+Article i.e if I have site A which sells 100,200,300 article nos.
My rowkeys are A100,A200,A300 respectively.
Now we want to scan the hbase table using the article number only.
Which can be present in multiple sites.
We tried performing a scan using substring comparator. But it takes a long time. 
Can anyone suggest a better salting or rowkey design for the same scenario.

Answer (score 1):

It doen't seems like this problem can be solved by simple rowkey redesign until you are able to exchange SiteId and ArticleId, 
but in that case you will have the same problem with searching by SiteId.
The reason for such behaviour is that HBase can't optimize a search by middle or last part of keys in anyway and it has to do a full scan.

Some solutions which you might think of:
1. Do several concurrent searches one per each site with condition `rowkey == SiteIdArticleId`. This would work fast if you have relatively small number of sites.
2. Do a `custom secondary index`. A second index table with AtricleId as rowkey and SiteIds as sell values.
3. Use `Apache Phoenix` which can do secondary indexing out of the box. (But check that it fits to need first)

In the second case you are able to perform get by key from index table and than from zero to multiple gets for each cell from the first get. This will work pretty fast, but require some space overhead.

**The second option in more details:**

Suppose your table colled `SiteToArticle` and the second table is colled `ArticleToSite`
When you do writes you write to both tables to the first as you usually do and to the second like `{"rowkey"=ArticleId, "SiteId"=siteId}`

When you do reads, firstly you read from `ArticleToSite`, then iterate over each `SiteId` create new get with key `SiteId:ArticleId` and perform the second batch of gets.
Code may look approximately like this:

```
byte[] articleId = "ArticleId".getBytes();
Get get = new Get(articleId).readAllVersions();
Table t = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("ArticleToSite"));

List<Get> gets = new ArrayList<>();
for (Cell c : t.get(get).getColumnCells("CF".getBytes(), "SiteId".getBytes())) {
    byte[] key = Bytes.add(CellUtil.cloneValue(c), ":".getBytes(), articleId);
    gets.add(new Get(key));
}
return connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("SiteToArticle")).get(gets);
```

Comment: Thankyou for you response can you please elaborate the second option in detail please ?
It would be of great help if you could suggest some blog where custom secondary index have been created.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can also check http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#secondary.indexes for more details.

Comment: But is it appropriate to maintain two tables of 1.5bn records ? As we have like 1000 sites and multiple articles across these sites.

Comment: It's a tradeoff for speeding up your queries.
But if you have only about 1000 sites, I think that it's better to just store them in some memory store and when you need to get an article by id you can generate a ```get``` for each site.